# Need to hide an xref only when it appears in a p element with a specific attribute

Tags: xslt

This is a re-work/new question after I got my previous one quite wrong by asking about the wrong element so here goes...

I'm trying to match and hide a xref within the following p element with the attribute of LC LRCaseName:

```
<p outputclass="LC LRCaseName"><i>Naseem Akhtar v Birmingham City Council</i> [2011] EWCA Civ 383 <xref href="#Public_PUBLICLAW_PLLR_2011PLLR002">Click here for transcript</xref></p>
```

so that I end up with "*Naseem Akhtar v Birmingham City Council [2011] EWCA Civ 383*"

We have other xrefs within other p outputclasses that we need to display otherwise I would hide it with <`xsl:template match="p/xref"/>` as per Dimitre Novatchev 's suggestion.

This particular xref will always contain "Click here for transcript" but the href will vary.

thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have tried the following code which doesn't make the xref background red:

```
<xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='LC LRCaseName']/xref">
    <fo:block background-color="red" >
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

but if I use this:

```
<xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='LC LRCaseName']">
    <fo:block background-color="red" >
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

It does make the entire P element background red and that includes the xref portion.

**EDIT 2:**

I have just had a thought, this system has another xsl file that has matches for xref. I'm wondering if my changes are being over-written by this file. Let me look into this further.

**EDIT 3:**

Just placed this very same code

```
<xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='LC LRCaseName']/xref" />
```

into dita2fo-links.xsl rather than the current file I was working on (dita2fo-elems.xsl) and it worked straight away. Obviously the links file is processed after the elems and all my matching was being overwritten by the later template matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match selector for the *xref* element could include the attribute value as well, like the following one:

```
p[@outputclass = 'LC LRCaseName']/xref
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. It doesn't seem to match. If I try: p[@outputclass = 'LC LRCaseName'] and set the background-color="red" it works on the entire P. But if I try p[@outputclass = 'LC LRCaseName']/xref it doesn't. Will update my question with this info

Comment: Mmmhhh... This must have to do with the FOP renderer: if you just use that transform/selector, you will get the desired transformed document.

Comment: I have just updated my question with a thought I have had. I have another file that matches xref's and I think this might be overwriting my match

Comment: Yes, the file: ditasfo-links.xsl must be processed after dita2fo-elems.xsl because as soon as I placed this code into the file it worked and hid the xref. I had it right hours ago but it was in the wrong file grrr

Comment: Hehe... It's the Murphy's law! :)

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation produces the wanted output**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='LC LRCaseName']/xref"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```